# Join a query with CROSS APPLY FOR JSON PATH

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL Server tables `ApplicationRoles` and `commonformsschema`. Applying a join between both table based on `SchemaId` column.

But `FOR JSON PATH` column name as `roles` results getting wrong.

Here is the select query:

```
SELECT
    fs1.SchemaId, JSON_QUERY(ar.newJson) as roles 
FROM
    commonformsschema fs1 
JOIN 
    ApplicationRoles ar1 on ar1.SchemaId = fs1.SchemaId 
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT 
         (SELECT 
              RoleName AS [role], 
              [create] AS [permissions.create], 
              [read] AS [permissions.read],
              [update] AS [permissions.update],
              [delete] AS [permissions.delete] 
          FROM 
              ApplicationRoles ar 
          WHERE 
              fs1.SchemaId = ar1.SchemaId 
          FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS newJson) ar 
WHERE
    fs1.Tenant IN ('test', 'All') 
    AND ar1.RoleName IN ('Project Manager', 'Read')
```

For the full table details,input please see the [db fiddler](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc087ff333e64506d732de2be1e1f6d6).

Current result:

| SchemaId | roles |
| --- | --- |
| 7a9a2521-45fb-4c9d-b7d9-e41927118119 | {"role":"Senior Construction Manager","permissions":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":true,"delete":true}} |
| ca5d8707-fee8-4a5b-ad61-813785e32575 | {"role":"Senior Construction Manager","permissions":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":true,"delete":true}} |

Expected result:

| SchemaId | roles |
| --- | --- |
| 7a9a2521-45fb-4c9d-b7d9-e41927118119 | {"role":"Project Manager","permissions":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":false,"delete":true}} |
| ca5d8707-fee8-4a5b-ad61-813785e32575 | {"role":"Project Manager","permissions":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":false,"delete":true}} |

How to solve this issue? Please any help. Any other detail required please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to JOIN the tables and generate the expected JSON for each row:

```
SELECT 
   fs1.SchemaId,
   (
   SELECT
      ar1.RoleName AS [role],
      ar1.[create] AS [permissions.create],
      ar1.[read] AS [permissions.read],
      ar1.[update] AS [permissions.update],
      ar1.[delete] AS [permissions.delete] 
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
   ) AS roles
FROM commonformsschema fs1 
JOIN ApplicationRoles ar1 ON ar1.SchemaId = fs1.SchemaId 
WHERE
   fs1.Tenant IN ('test', 'All') AND 
   ar1.RoleName IN ('Project Manager', 'Read')
```

Results:

| SchemaId | roles |
| --- | --- |
| 7a9a2521-45fb-4c9d-b7d9-e41927118119 | {"role":"Project Manager","permissions":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":false,"delete":true}} |
| ca5d8707-fee8-4a5b-ad61-813785e32575 | {"role":"Project Manager","permissions":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":false,"delete":true}} |